# frequency function

Tags: probability, functions

The random variable $\xi$ has the following pdf:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}kx^2&0<x<6\\
0&\text{else}\end{cases}$$
a) determine $k$
b) determine $P(\xi<2)$

I dont know where to start. After looking at an example I started to think that the interval for $\xi$ is [0, 5] and then P($\xi$ $<=x$) = $x/5$ so then k would be $1/5$ but thats very wrong.

**The answers are:**

a: $1/72$

b:$1/27$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: You need the total probability to sum to one.

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \,dx = \int_0^6 kx^2\,dx = 1
$$

solve for $k$.

For the second part you solve the integral:

$$
\int_0^2 kx^2 \,dx
$$

(where you use the $k$ that you found in part a.

Comment: Is there any reason why you put the first integral equal to 1? Is it because the sum of all possibilities are 1?

Comment: Yes. The total probability (from $-\infty$ to $+ \infty$) needs to be 1. Since your random variable is nonzero only over the interval $(0,6)$, that is the only part of the integral that you need to evaluate (everywhere else, it is zero).